# Is the main(String[] args) method predefined or user-defined in java

Tags: java

The main() method is starting point of all java programs. All predefined methods are declared/defined in some class like **println()** method is defined in **PrintStream** class
Now **WHERE** is the **main()** method **declared/defined**? Its not present in the Object class, where I presumed it to be  . 
Or is it that the main() method is a user-defined method. If so, why can't we say

```
    public static void main(int args){}
```

or

```
    public void main(String args){}
```

Please someone explain this,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the main method is defined in the class you compile/run

Comment: this looks like a question posted minutes ago... maybe the homework for the weekend somewhere .....

Comment: You can perfectly define those two methods. They just aren't valid entry points for a Java program, because Java expects a static method, named main, returning void, and taking an array of Strings as argument.

Comment: Did you read [javadoc main method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN) ?

Comment: yes your right ,JRE calling exactly same format as you said .so main() method is some were declared. were it was declared this is my actual dout    Actually this question was asked in interview which i was attended.i given ans exactly as you said but he is not satisfied with ans @JBNizet

Comment: It's declared in your class. Java looks for such a declaration in the class you ask it to execute, and if it doesn't find it, it will display an error message and stop. That's all.

Comment: so I can say It was user defined method @JBNizet

Comment: Yes, you can say it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* say:

```
public void main(String args){}
```

It's just that your program won't run, but it *does* compile.

The `main` method seems like magic at first sight, doesn't it?

It looks like a user-defined method (it is). yet all programs start here.

The trick here is `java`. When you run your program, you do a command like this, right?

```
java MyClass
```

Immediately after that, Java finds a `.class` file named `MyClass` and finds a class called `MyClass` in that file. Then it will automatically look for a `main` method with the exact signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

And then Java calls this. If you declare it any other way, Java can't find it.

Note that this is not a language feature. The JLS does not mention this at all. It's just how the `java` command is designed.

Comment: you are right ,but My actual Questions is it was predefined or user defined method.

Comment: It's a user defined. Maybe I was not clear enough, but my first sentence is saying that you _can_ declare it another way. The program still compiles but it won't run. I am kind of implying that it is defined by you. Sorry! @Srinu

Answer (score 1):

Simply because the `java` program (i.e., java.exe on Windows) was written to use `public static void main(String[])` as the entry point.  This is not a fundamental feature of the language.  It's entirely possible that some other program could use a different method as the entry point.